# coverage.py gives "No source for code", despite .coveragerc seemingly telling it where the code is

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

If I invoke `python3 -m coverage` run ... inside a docker container, I get a `.coverage` file as desired.

However, if I try to generate the `html` or text reports using that `.coverage` file outside of the container, I get:

```
No source for code: '/opt/anomaly/backplane/__init__.py'.
Aborting report output, consider using -i.
```

`./backplane/__init__.py` exists, and I have the following `.coveragerc` in the same directory:

```
[paths]
source =
    ./
    /opt/anomaly/.
```

It seems like `coverage.py` doesn't know that `.` and `/opt/anomaly` should be considered the same thing, despite the `.coveragerc` file intended to tell `coverage.py` that they are.

I've googled quite a bit, and found nothing.

I also generated the reports inside the container, and that worked fine.  But I'd really rather generate them outside the container.

---

Update:
Ned provided the useful information that only `coverage combine` uses `[paths]` in the `.coveragerc`.

Here's what I'm up against at this point:

```
+ ./bin/terminate-api
+ sleep 2
+ lses
+ ls -l .coverage .api-coverage
ls: cannot access '.coverage': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 13358 Jul 22 14:15 .api-coverage
+ python3 -m coverage combine .api-coverage
+ lses
+ ls -l .coverage .api-coverage
ls: cannot access '.api-coverage': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 dstromberg dstromberg 13358 Jul 22 14:15 .coverage
+ python3 -m coverage html
No source for code: '/opt/anomaly/backplane/__init__.py'.
Aborting report output, consider using -i.
```

BTW, I've now tried with a relative path in .coveragerc, and also with an absolute path in .coveragerc.  Neither is working for me at the moment.

Note that .api-coverage and .coverage have the same length - I'm thinking .coverage should have a different length because of the changed paths.  For the relative path, .coverage should be smaller, and with the absolute path, .coverage should be larger.

BTW, I'm using:

```
$ python3 -m coverage --version
below cmd output started 2019 Mon Jul 22 02:33:02 PM PDT
Coverage.py, version 4.5.3 with C extension
Documentation at https://coverage.readthedocs.io
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to generate `HTML` inside of the container?

Comment: I just tried replacing the lone . with an equivalent absolute path, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon Yes, generating the reports inside the container works.

Comment: The `[paths]` setting is only used by the "coverage combine" command.

Comment: @NedBatchelder That sounds like an important clue.  Sadly, I'm still not getting a usable .coverage. I'm going to add specifics to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running executables `.coverage` requires runtime environment, which in your case can be provided inside the container instead of your host machine.

This combined with deleting the trailing /. from my .coveragerc's /opt/anomaly/. path appears to have solved the problem.